# Play Framework 2.3 CSRF Protection

Tags: playframework-2.0, csrf

I am using Java Play Framework 2.3.5 and want to add a global CSRF protection as described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaCsrf

If I Copy&Paste the following code:

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
  @Override
  public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
    return new Class[]{CSRFFilter.class};
    }
}
```

The csrfToken value will get concatenated with the normal cookie value instead of creating a new cookie as I would have expected.

```
PLAY_SESSION="b8c5eead5e95be30edaccec5680aa58fb1b5cae5-csrfToken=4dfb0c575ac272f9b9e457e40a287c81972baec5-1414171392926-af3ee2c36fdbdbf65c68dcc4"; path=/; domain=localhost; HttpOnly
```

I am not aware of messing with the Play session management in any way. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The following options can be configured in `application.conf`:
>
> `csrf.cookie.name` - If configured, Play will store the CSRF token in a cookie with the given name, instead of in the session.